# Does numpy.ndarray class also have magic method like __init__ constructor to construct its object like other python classes?

Tags: python, numpy

I have three questioned mentioned below
1:-for example when we say arr = np.array([1,2,3])
what happen internally? does the array function internally call numpy.ndarray constructor to create this object? or some other mechanism is followed?

2:-New arrays can be constructed using the routines detailed in Array creation routines like above, and also by using the low-level ndarray constructor:
ndarray(shape[, dtype, buffer, offset, …])
does this internaly call **init** constructor like in normal python? if not then can how is the constructor written for it to create ndarray object?

3:- does routine and function means the same thing?

Comment: `np.ndarray` is the low level array creator, but don't use it unless you already have a buffer.  Documentation on subclassing ndarray explains more how `__new__` and `__init__` are used,

Comment: 3- TL;DR: Yes. Too many details: Python does not distinguish between routines and functions. The term most commonly used is "function". According to Google, some ancient IBM language distinguished between a procedure (a routine that does not return a value) and a function (a route that returns a value), but Python makes no such distinction. In fact, in Python, if a function has no return statement, it's still returning a value, namely `None`.

Comment: 1- and 2- : when you have a python library written in C/C++, like numpy, it's been written to be much more optimized than regular Python code. What happens internally is whatever the implementer figured out was necessary to implement the documented interface. If you really care to know how it's done, it'll take a lot of digging. I recommend just using the interface as documented and now worrying about how it's implemented.

Comment: NumPy provides a lot of different ways to allocate arrays: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-creation.html#routines-array-creation . `numpy.ndarray(...)` will give you an array with uninitialized (or arbitrarily initialized) values, whereas the other ones will set the initial values in one way or another. I would guess the other ones probably all call the `numpy.ndarray` constructor in one way or another, because that's the most logical thing to do if you're implementing a library like this, but there's no promise that's the case.

Comment: In the `numpy-capi` docs I find this `c` function call creating a ndarray "from scratch" https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#from-scratch